# Django model: NULLable field

Tags: django, postgresql, model, null

I'm working on a django project where I need a DateField to sometimes be empty. My model looks like this:

```
#models.py
end = models.DateField(default=None, blank=True)
```

But when I run `python manage.py sql myapp` the sql statement always end up being

```
CREATE TABLE "myapp_date" (
"end" date NOT NULL
);
```

Therefore my field isn't nullable and I can't understand what I should do to make it so. Any idea would be appreciated !

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You should use

```
end = models.DateField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

Basically `blank` allows you to pass it a null value, but `null` tells the database to accept null values.

Comment: I'm ashamed, I thought I had already tried that; I guess I hadn't tried the three arguments at the same time... It's working now, thank you for the help !!

Comment: No problem, happens to all of us :)

Comment: It did not work for me, actually I am adding date field later, there are already some values without date field.